# How to automatically upload compiled coffeescript files in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, coffeescript

I use automatic deploy through FTP. Everything worked well until I started to use coffeescript and its filewatcher feature which recompiles my .coffee file into .js file on every change.

Problem is that IDEA don't want to upload these compiled files like others. So I have manually press hotkey to upload compiled file after every change, which I want to see on the server.

How can I do it more convenient to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an [option to upload external changes automatically](http://img542.imageshack.us/img542/9481/20130416230153.png).

Right now IDEA will not perform synchronization after file watcher is invoked, so you will need to do `File` | `Synchronize`, IDE will detect the changes and upload them.

Next update will have an option for the file watcher to perform synchronization after execution as the result of addressing [this feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-7065).

Comment: "[x] upload external changes" worked like a charm!  You made my day.

Answer (score 0):

this feature request concerns to a possibility to synchronize all files in output directory on every change (required by some transpilers). But, AFAIK, this is not the case for CoffeeScript compiler - synchronization should work there. Do the generated js files appear in the Project View as soon as the compilation completes, or do you have to synchronize the view manually to see changes? In the latter case something must be wrong with file watcher configuration (output path set incorrectly, for example). If files are synchronized correctly, setting 'upload external changes' option should do the thing